# I cannot create category and sub-categories list in home page,django

Tags: python, django, templates, mptt

I can create a category page with sub-categories in a new template but i cannot list all my sub-categories in home page. All i need is a logic to work in home page.

Here is my models.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True,related_name='children',db_index=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
    
    def get_slug_list(self):
        try:
            ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        except:
            ancestors = []
        else:
            ancestors = [ i.slug for i in ancestors]
        slugs = []
        for i in range(len(ancestors)):
            slugs.append('/'.join(ancestors[:i+1]))
        return slugs

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product:product-category',args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product:product-detail',kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug,
            
        })
```

here is my views.py

```
def product_list(request,category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    
    return render(
        request,'product/home.html',{
            'category':category,
            'categories':categories,
            'products':products
        }
    )


def show_category(request,hierarchy= None):
    category_slug = hierarchy.split('/')
    parent = None
    root = Category.objects.all()

    for slug in category_slug[:-1]:
        parent = root.get(parent=parent, slug = slug)

    try:
        instance = Category.objects.get(parent=parent,slug=category_slug[-1])
    except:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Product, slug = category_slug[-1])
        return render(request, 'product/product.html', {'instance':instance})
    else:
        return render(request, 'product/categories.html', {'instance':instance})
```

I used this logic in my template but it doesn't work. So any help to display the categories and sub-categories list would be massively appreciated.

```
      {% for c in categories %}
        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.parent }}</a>
       {% for i in c.children.all %}
       <a href="#">{{ i.name }}</a>
       {% endfor %}
        
        
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the problem you are facing? If you are getting an error, please post that with the question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is not very clear.
But irrespective, have a look at this [template](https://github.com/addu390/django-pyblog/blob/master/blog/templates/base.html) for the categories [view](https://github.com/addu390/django-pyblog/blob/master/blog/views.py),

Comment: This doesn't help. All the things are working but when it comes to display categories list in template, i got nothing just blank. The logic in my template isn't working with the logic in views.